# How to group by values in a row in F#?

Tags: f#

If I have uploaded a CSV file and I have it split up into rows within a SEQUENCE.

If there are also multiple instances of one value in lets say ROW 1, how do I average the values in ROW 2 by the values in ROW 1, so I now only have one instance of each value in ROW 1.
{This is just an example, and ROW 1 and ROW 2 are theoretical.}

Be aware that I am working with a sequence.

Example of data and ideal result is below:

What is Given:

```
Row 1 --- Row 2 (Dollars)   
2010  ---    50000.198  
2010  ---    45151.451  
2011  ---    75641.372  
2011  ---    91652.710  
2012  ---    11281.450  
2012  ---    70046.154  
2012  ---    97778.054  
2013  ---    555574.501 
2013  ---    78921.215
```

What I Want:

```
Row 1 --- Row 2
2010  ---    47575.825
2011  ---    93647.041
2012  ---    59701.886 
2013  ---    317247.858
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you give an example of some values you'd have in your CSV file and what you're trying to do with them?

Comment: I added an example. The data really should not matter at all in this case. I just need to know how to do this because lack of F# literature on this topic.

Comment: do you know how to read from a file?

Comment: Are referring to columns as rows?  I'm very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've already parsed the CSV file and pulled values into a sequence. For this example, let's assume you pulled it into a list of tuples with the year as the first element and the cost as the second, equivalent to this:

```fs
let costByYear =
    [
    (2010,50000.198)
    (2010,45151.451)
    (2011,75641.372)
    (2011,91652.710)
    (2012,11281.450)
    (2012,70046.154)
    (2012,97778.054)
    (2013,555574.501)
    (2013,78921.215)
    ]
```

You could use a few `Seq` functions to group by the year ([`Seq.groupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.groupby%5b%27t%2c%27key%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)) and then average the cost ([`Seq.average`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.average%5b%5et%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)):

```fs
let avgCostPerYear =
    let avg (year, costs) = (year, Seq.average <| Seq.map snd costs)
    Seq.groupBy fst >> Seq.map avg
```

Running this:

```fs
printfn "%A" (avgCostPerYear costByYear)
```

yields:

```fs
seq
  [(2010, 47575.8245); (2011, 83647.041); (2012, 59701.886); (2013, 317247.858)]
```